# Python remote debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, remote

How do I debug remote python/twisted code from within Emacs?

The closest I got with an internet search was [Geben](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/), if I understand correctly, but it has not been maintained for a few years now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try qdb

https://github.com/quantopian/qdb

An emacs interface (qbd.el) is included:
https://github.com/quantopian/qdb/tree/master/client/emacs

Answer (score 0):

I do not write python code in Emacs, but I would try `pdb` (Emacs built-in python debugger) on a remote python file.

Comment: Thanks! i would like to control the debugging through my local files. It can be done in WingIDE for example.